# Why is there a bar on the bottom of my Android app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a main activity that shows the camera, and a fragment, which has FABs in a frame layout at the bottom of my app. I want them to look somewhat like how the android lock screen looks (with the camera button on it while still being able to see the background/activity behind it). I changed the theme to make the background translucent - thinking the frame layout was just maintaining a color - but now I have a bar that incorrectly shows the home screen at the bottom, and changing the frame layout does not change the bar. I want to just show the activity - not the home screen - so I need this bar to go away or at least show the activity instead of the home screen. I'm not sure why it's there. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Images:

1. [Image of app incorrectly showing home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeMuq.jpg)
2. [Image of app showing background color that I don't want (I want it to show the activity or just not have a bar there)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz34f.jpg)

AndroidManifest.xml snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
tools:context="com.example.android.camera2basic.MainActivity" />
```

fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<include layout="@layout/drawer_main"
    android:id="@+id/drawerInclude" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/control_background" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSwap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_swap"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/control_background" />

</FrameLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- App style -->
    <style name="MaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style> <!-- android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen -->

    <!-- My translucent style -->
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: The point behind using a translucent theme is that you *want* to show the contents of the activity behind yours. If that is not what you want, stop using a translucent theme.

Comment: Even when I made everything transparent, the bar at the bottom still had a color, that's why I had to adjust the theme to see different outcomes. I'm not sure how to make it so I can see just the camera activity without the bar showing the home screen or some color.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't really understand your problem, but apply this code, this will make it full screen.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<include layout="@layout/drawer_main"
    android:id="@+id/drawerInclude" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/control_background" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSwap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_swap"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/control_background" />

</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Do let me know, if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that is not what I wanted. I would like to have the camera activity take up the entire screen with the FABs remaining where they are. But there is a bar on the bottom of the screen (see links to screen shots in my original post) that I can't figure out how to get rid of, or at least be see-through so I could see the activity behind it, not the home screen.